# Jump Link Inside an iFrame

Tags: html, firefox, iframe, hyperlink

Inside an iframe (on *page-A*), I have a simple page (*page-B*) that has a few jump links (e.g. `<a href="#my-id">jump link</a>`) to different sections of the page (*page-B*). The iframe height is preset to be longer than *page-B*'s height; this is a requirement.

For some reasons, the jump links didn't work on FF (I am on Mac/FF 10.0.2); however, it worked properly on Safari and IE8. This is the **[sample page](http://labs.siku-siku.com/experiment/05/)**.

Code of page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Jump Link Test on an iFrame</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Page that has an iFrame</h1>
<iframe width="100%" height="2000" src="./iframe.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Code of iframe.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>iFrame Content</title>
<style type="text/css">
.box {
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
#box1 {
    background-color: #f00;
}
#box2 {
    background-color: #f0f;
}
#box3 {
    background-color: #00f;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#box1">Box 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#box2">Box 2</a></li>

    <li><a href="#box3">Box 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div>
    <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
    <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
    <div id="box3" class="box"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: If I set the iframe height < *page-B*'s height, the problem will be solved. However, unfortunately this isn't an option given my situation because I have no access to *page-A*.

Comment: Same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569309/how-to-avoid-anchors-in-iframes-to-scroll-parent-page#comment12134920_9569309

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### This is not possible with HTML only.

As you can read on the Firefox [Bug Report Nr. 638598](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=638598) this is mentioned long time ago! Also many people don't like that behavior, but [Jonas Sicking says in his comment](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=638598#c11) that this will never change. He sees that as a feature that firefox prevent this potential hacking functionality.

if you don't know him [read here that](http://hacks.mozilla.org/author/sicking/) he is the Tech Lead of the [web-api](/questions/tagged/web-api) project at mozilla as well as an editor for the [indexeddb](/questions/tagged/indexeddb) and [file-api](/questions/tagged/file-api) specifications at [W3C](http://www.w3.org/).

Other people tried to find solutions like [Matthew](http://matthewmanela.com/blog/making-linking-between-anchors-in-an-iframe-work-in-firefox-4-and-above/) but this example didn't work in my short test case with your html structure. [Some others say](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=638598#c13) that it should work with JavaScript and the `scrollTo()` Function.

I'm sorry for saying that this is a limitation of FireFox only, but hope you are happy to be safe in the knowledge about that problem.

Comment: This is working in newest FF 32.0.3. I didn't see any problems now.

Answer (score 15):

I already ran into this issue. In my case I could not use a javascript solution because my iframe was in a different domain and I had no access to the parent page.

## But there is a HTML workaround.

Change your link from this:

```
<a href="#my-id">jump link</a>
```

To this:

```
<a target="_parent" href="http://parenturl.com/#my-id">jump link</a>
```

And create a invisible `<div id="my-id"></div>` in your parent page and position it using CSS.

Comment: Unless I missed your point, positioning the invisible `<div>` might be problematic because the parent doesn't know it in advance.

Comment: This technique only works if you know where your iframe will be embed,   I used it to add an iframe to a YouTube brand channel. I knew that the iframe will only be rendered via the YouTube page so I used one of the ids that already existed in the YouTube page as a anchor link

Comment: This sounds to be only working in a special case where you know much about the iframes content. Not really the thing he was asking for. But a nice idea in your special case ;)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I am using chrome and different domain for iframe parent.

Answer (score -1):

Mmm, just a thought, have you reset margins for the iframe? FF tends to do weird things when you don't explicitly specify margin attributes.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the margin.